# Why the key is not shown in the HTML rendered page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've written the following code:

```
const TableRow = ({row, i}) => (
<tr key={row.barcode}>
  <td>{i}</td>
  <td>{row.name}</td>
  <td>{row.description}</td>
  <td>{row.brand}</td>
  <td>{row.barcode}</td>
</tr>
);
```

that is called in another component render() function that is

```
var table = (<Table striped bordered condensed hover>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Username</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {
                                this.state.products.map((row, i) =>
                                    <TableRow row={row} id={i}/>
                                )
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </Table>);
 return table;
```

The problem is that in the rendered HTML all the `<td>` tags don't have any key property so

```
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>NAME</td>
  <td>DESCR</td>
  <td>NDARB</td>
  <td>800800800</td>
 </tr>
```

without any key property.

Comment: The code is not completely understable can you paste a fiddle or codepen link illustrating the problem

Answer (score 0):

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed.

Keys are used internally and are never rendered in DOM. If you want to use it as an identifier, use `id` attribute in addition.

Ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Answer (score 0):

That's because `Key` is a React property.
From the React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys):

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity

They are not rendered into the actual DOM, they are only used internally.